# React: El state es diferente para cada componente

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de To Do's, tengo dos componentes, el componente `ToDoApp` que básicamente es el componente principal donde se listan los to do's y donde también se crean los to dos, y el componente `ToDoElement` que está conformado por el input donde se describe el to do, junto con los botones submit, clear y delete. El submit es para guardar el to do, el clear es para limpiar el input, y el delete es para eliminar el componente `ToDoElement`.

Estoy intentando crear cada `ToDoElement` de manera dinámica. En el componente `ToDoApp` hay un botón para crear un nuevo `ToDo`, este botón lo que hace es añadir un nuevo `ToDoElement` al componente `ToDoApp`.

En el componente principal (`ToDoApp`) tengo un

```javascript
const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([])
```

Para manejar la lista de los `ToDoElement` generados cada vez que se hace clic al botón para crear un nuevo To Do.

El problema es que cuando quiero eliminar un `ToDoElement` de la lista de `ToDos`, al parecer cada toDos es diferente para cada `ToDoElement`. Por ejemplo, si en el `toDos` tengo almacenados tres `ToDoElements`, y en el método `handleUnmount` que es para eliminar el componente clickeado hago un

```javascript
console.log(toDos.length);
```

me muestra un valor diferente por cada `ToDoElement`.

- Para el primer `ToDoElement` generado, `toDos.length` es igual a 0.
- Para el segundo `ToDoElement` generado, `toDos.length` es igual a 1.
- Para el tercer `ToDoElement` generado, `toDos.length` es igual a 2, y así sucesivamente.

Lo ideal es que para todos los `ToDoElements` generados el `toDos` sea el mismo.

Aquí muestro el código tanto del `ToDoApp` como del `ToDoElement`
(el método `handleUnmount` se crea en el `ToDoApp` y se le pasa mediante props al `ToDoElement`)

```js
const {useState, useRef} = React;

const ToDoApp = ()=>{
    const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([]);
    const handleNewToDo = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setToDos([...toDos, <ToDoElement onUnmount={handleUnmount} id={toDos.length + 1}/>]);
    }
    const handleUnmount = (e, id) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("toDos.length: " + toDos.length);
        //setToDos(toDos.filter(element => element.id !== id));
    }
    return (
        <div className="AppContainer">
            <div className="Form ListContainer">
                <h2>To Do List</h2>
                <ul className="ToDoList">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form className="form-control Form" >
                <div className="ToDoZone">
                {
                    (
                        toDos.length === 0 ? 
                            <div className="h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <h2 className="text-center">Create a new To Do<br />+</h2>
                            </div> 
                        : 
                            toDos
                    )
                }
                </div>
                <div className="NewToDoContainer">
                    <button type="button" 
                            className="btn btn-primary NewToDoBtn"
                            onClick={(e)=>{handleNewToDo(e)}}        
                    >
                        New To Do
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

const ToDoElement = (props)=>{
    const input = {
        data: ""
    };
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        input.data = e.target.value;
    }    
    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Submit:' + input.data);
    };

    const handleReset = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        inputRef.current.value = "";
        input.data = "";
    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-3">
            <input type="text" ref={inputRef} className="form-control" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="To Do"/>
            <div className="ButtonContainer mt-3">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e =>{handleSubmit(e)}}>Submit</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning ml-5" onClick={e =>handleReset(e)}>Clear</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger ml-5" onClick={e =>props.onUnmount(e, props.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <ToDoApp />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Lo que quiero es que el toDos sea igual para todos, o sea, porque cuando doy click al botón Delete del ToDoElement y se ejecuta el método handleUnmount, lo que debería de hacer es cambiar el toDos mediante el setToDos para que el componente ToDoElement que se quiere eliminar ya no aparezca cuando se vuelva a renderizar la aplicación.

Comment: Un comentario al margen. En la función `handleNewToDo` en vez de hacer esto para usar el estado anterior: `setToDos([...toDos, <ToDoElement onUnmount={handleUnmount} id={toDos.length + 1}/>])` deberías hacer lo siguiente: `setToDos(prevState => [...prevState , <ToDoElement onUnmount={handleUnmount} id={prevState .length + 1}/>])` puedes verlo mas en detalle en la documentación https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @AndresGardiol me funcionó tu sugerencia, muchas gracias, pero ahora no se por qué el método handleUnmount, que ejecuta la instrucción ```setToDos(toDos.filter(element => element.id !== id));``` solo me devuelve los toDos hasta el elemento que se quiere eliminar, por ejemplo, si tengo los elementos 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (haciendo que estos elementos son cada ToDoElement), y quisiera eliminar el elemento 3, el setToDos solo establece los elementos 1 y 2, los elementos 4 y 5 no los deja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que se podría hacer de otra manera. Las funciones estar en el componente principal y el componente ToDoElement solo tener el código jsx, delegar la ejecucion de las funciones en el padre. Además de no guardar en la variable toDos elementos JSX, mejor un array de objetos y con estos valores renderizar tantos todoelements como haya. Quedaría asi el codigo.

Componente APP:

```
function App() {
const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([]);

const handleNewToDo = e =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const newId = toDos.length === 0 ? 1 : toDos[toDos.length - 1].id + 1;
  console.log(toDos.map(x => x.id), Math.max([1,2,]))
  setToDos([...toDos, {id: newId, title: ""}]);
}

const handleUnmount = (id) =>{
  console.log(toDos);
  setToDos(toDos.filter(x => x.id !== id))
}

const handleChange = (value,id)=>{
  setToDos(toDos.map(x => {
  const newTodo = {...x}
  if(x.id === id) newTodo.title = value;
  return newTodo
  }));

}

 const handleSubmit = (id)=>{
    // alert(`Submit: ${input.data}`);
 };

const handleReset = (id)=>{
    handleChange("", id);
}

  return (
  <div className="AppContainer">
      <div className="Form ListContainer">
          <h2>To Do List</h2>
          <ul className="ToDoList">
          </ul>
      </div>
      <form className="form-control Form" >
          <div className="ToDoZone">
          {
              (
                  toDos.length === 0 ? 
                      <div className="h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                          <h2 className="text-center">Create a new To Do<br />+</h2>
                      </div> 
                  : 
                      toDos.map((x,index) =>{
                        return <ToDoElement key={index} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                                 handleReset={handleReset} onUnmount={handleUnmount} data={x} />
                      })
              )
          }
          </div>
          <div className="NewToDoContainer">
              <button type="button" 
                      className="btn btn-primary NewToDoBtn"
                      onClick={(e)=>{handleNewToDo(e)}}        
              >
                  New To Do
              </button>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>)
}
```

Este el componente ToDoElement:

```
import React from "react";

const ToDoElement = (props)=>{

    const {handleChange, handleSubmit, handleReset, onUnmount, data} = props;

    return (
    <div className="mt-3">
        <input type="text" value={data.title} className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e.target.value, data.id)} placeholder="To Do"/>
        <div className="ButtonContainer mt-3">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => handleSubmit(data.id)}>Submit</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning ml-5" onClick={e => handleReset(data.id)}>Clear</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger ml-5" onClick={e => onUnmount(data.id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
);
}

export default ToDoElement;
```

Falta la funcion submit, que no se que quieres hacer. Pensaba que podría ser guardar el valor del texto, pero ya lo voy guardando en el onchange.

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Por qué sugieres no guardar elementos jsx en el toDos? qué ventajas tendría?

Comment: Pues para que crear los elementos cuando puedes guardar solo los datos. Y si posteriormente quieres guardarlos en algún sitio??? Aparte que estarías creando 3 funciones para cada elemento

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudó